# Getting 404 Not found in Postman for a Get request

Tags: spring, spring-boot, api, rest, postman

I have below controller class

```
@RestController
public class EmpController {

    @Autowired
    EmpService empService;
    @Autowired
    Test t;
    
    @GetMapping("/fetch")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Employee>> empDetails(){
        //List<Employee> emp = empService.empDetails();
        List<Employee> emp = t.get();
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Employee>>(emp, HttpStatus.OK);
        
    }
}
```

When i try to hit the request in Postman using url
http://localhost:8080/fetch    i get 404 not found as a response.
Server.port is by default is 8080

I tried using this also
@GetMapping(value="/fetch")

Comment: Are you sure that server has successfully started? You should see the message in the console of your IDE, either telling that the server has started on a particular port, or that there's some kind of problem.

Comment: Can you please share snapshot of your project folder structure